# How can I group months and filtered by year in MongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have json that contain the following objects; cancellation_date and management_fee. I want to take out months from my cancellation_date and group them by year, displaying the total of cancellation by month.

Here is the JSON. The only 2 objects to work on are management_fee and cancellation_date (I want to have the total of management_fee lost per month grouped by years). Here is an example with fake data.

```
{
        "_id": "5d30c4ac5fbf3c250bb6",
        "user": "5d2f594faa064d82c47c",
        "department_director": "Director 1",
        "account_manager": "Account Manager 1",
        "fronter": "Fronter 2",
        "closer": "Closer 1",
        "order_number": "EDVRV20202020202",
        "business_name": "Busines Name 1",
        "business_website": "www.businessname1.com",
        "client_name": "Client 1",
        "client_phone": 9090909090,
        "client_email": "email1@company.com",
        "type_of_service": "PPC Local",
        "management_fee": 599,
        "sales_date": "2017-04-23T00:00:00.000Z",
        "cancellation_date": "2018-04-23T00:00:00.000Z",
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "Florida",
        "client_budget": "Below",
        "daily_budget": 400,
        "monthly_budget": 20,
        "cancellation_reason": "Business Closed",
        "industry_type": "Real State",
        "cancellation_comments": "Just a comment 3",
        "createdAt": "2019-07-18T19:12:44.824Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-07-18T19:12:44.824Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Here are some code that I've done so far:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
router.get('/time_series', auth, async (req, res) => {

    try {

      const model_CancellationKPI = await CancellationKPI.aggregate(
        [
           {
             $group : {
                _id : { month: { $month: "$cancellation_date" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$cancellation_date" }, year: { $year: "$cancellation_date" } },
                totalPrice: { $sum: "$management_fee" },
                averageQuantity: { $avg: "$management_fee" },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
             }
           }
        ]
     )

     res.json(model_CancellationKPI);

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message); 
      res.status(500).send('Server Error')
    }
  });
```

And this is the output:

For instance, in the first JSON shows the total of cancellation in the month 7, day 15 and 2019 with 499

[image]

But, I want to have an output like this:

[image]

Comment: it would be easy for anyone to write queries if you've sample documents given in question, Please provide some sample documents.

Comment: what do you mean by sample documents?

Comment: You are doing this 3rd or 4th time. You should try to understand people need document in JSON format not screenshots. So please update your question

Comment: @ManfredTijerino : mongoDB documents, I mean actual data that you're trying to access..

Comment: I added the JSON with fake date that I am currently working on.

Comment: @srinivas: I would appreciate your support on this.

Comment: @ManfredTijerino : not sure whether you'll be able to convert your cancellation_date that far means month as a string, maybe you need to get results from DB and do some work in node.js code . Are you still looking for help ?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for  help in regards this code.